# how I get a number outside [0,255] when doing a converson from int to char?

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

I do not see why conversion from int to char gives me a number outside the range of (char)? Here is my C++ program:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  printf("%c\n",(char) 246 );
  printf("%d\n", (char) (246) );
}
```

I get

```
\366
-10
```

Any explanation? What I need here is a conversion from int to char

```
char int2char(int i);
```

that returns the truncated 'i' to the char. Of course, one can do this by some `(i mod 256)` but I am looking for a way that uses type conversion to do this. Any idea?

Comment: `-10` is in the range of `char`

Comment: 366 is 246 in octal. '%c' doesn't print the value of the number, it prints the character represented by it, and it appears your system/console doesn't have a character so it prints the escaped octal representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute:

```
printf("%d\n", (char) (246) );
```

It is equivalent to executing:

```
char c = 246;
int i = c;
printf("%d\n", i);
```

The tricky part is what happens in the line

```
char c = 246;
```

`246` is stored as `11110110` in binrary.

It looks like on your platform, `char` is `signed`. When `char` is `signed`, the integer value of that binary number is equal to `-10`. Hence, the value of `c` is set to `-10`, and the value of `i` is also set to `-10`.

Answer (score 3):

The native `char` type could be either signed or unsigned. It seems that it's signed on your machine.

If you want to make sure the result is within `[0, 255]` range, use `unsigned char` instead.

```
static_cast<unsigned char>(246)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your C++ compiler treats `char` as a *signed* 8-bit integer, with range -128 to 127, rather than as an *unsigned* 8-bit integer with a range of 0 to 255.

The problem isn't the `int`-to-`char` conversion, but the `char`-to-`int` conversion, which can be done with either casting (`i = (unsigned char) c` or `i = static_cast<unsigned char>(c)`) or bitmasking (`i = c & 0xFF`).